# Can I block a specific video on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Can I block a specific video on YouTube, so that it is not shown in my future search results?

Comment: I'd use this to permanently block Rick Ashley

Answer (score 1):

Not via YouTube-native features, no. There are however extensions that allow you to do it, namely Video Blocker (available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/video-blocker/) and others) - though that one blocks all videos from a certain channel.